# MoveIt: how to use class MoveGroup::MoveGroupImpl?

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I would like to use the function `void setReplanningDelay(double delay)` belonging to class MoveGroup::MoveGroupImpl, because I need to decrease the 2 seconds default value of `replan_delay_`.
How could I implement that function? An example of code would be really helpful.

I think another option is to manually decrease that value, but this would require installing Moveit in the workspace I guess, but I would leave this option as the last resort.

ROS version: Kinetic
Ubuntu: 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306023/moveit:-how-to-use-class-movegroup::movegroupimpl?/) by [enrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/34982/enrico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2018-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming you're talking about MoveGroupInterfaceImpl, since you're on Kinetic and MoveGroup was changed to MoveGroupInterface.

MoveGroupInterface uses the PImpl technique (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl). In order to access `void setReplanningDelay(double delay)` you will need to to build your own MoveIt and add a function to the MoveGroupInterface which in turn calls Impl's function.

```
void moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::setReplanningDelay(double delay)
{
  impl_->setReplanningDelay(delay);
}
```

This is taken from [MoveIt's GitHub](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/kinetic-devel/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp) (there's a bunch of similar functions at the very end).

---

Originally posted by [pcoenen](https://answers.ros.org/users/30604/pcoenen/) with karma: 249 on 2018-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1